# Newsletter layout crashes with Gmail

Tags: html, css, inline, newsletter, mailchimp

I've actually created a template on Mailchimp. I used a basic template of Mailchimp and transformed it into the design they gave me. I used the the [CSS inline tool](http://beaker.mailchimp.com/inline-css) of Mailchimp to insert all the code in an inline mode as Gmail does not accept any style on the header. I only  have this issue on Gmail, the rest work perfectly. What can I do?

[image]

As the code is long I inserted it in a fiddle if you wish to check it out:

http://jsfiddle.net/z27Bw/

I need a`n` answer as its a mystery for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

Write first tr code like this

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2" height="281"> </td>
</tr>
```

instead of

```
<tr>
<td width="35" height="281"> </td>
<td class="headerContent"> </td>
</tr
```

>

and then put that big header image inside it.

Comment: YOu think the issue is with the header? why colspan 2?

Comment: I still get the same layout error on Gmail. Do you have other alternatives?

Comment: I removed on column and then tested on gmail and its working fine, here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Mohinder/U6pFy/

Comment: this is what I removed from line 377 <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>

Comment: Yes I was also checking that out, that is what is not working correctly. This is the margin at the left of all the body content. If I take it out the layour works well, but how can I add a margin for the whole body? Margin and padding do not work correctly right? If it works I will give your answer as correct!

Comment: Simple just decrease the width of its parent table and content will come in center.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39660/discussion-between-minder-saini-and-daniel-ramirez-escudero)

Comment: @line 377 <td width="15">&nbsp;</td> was the error breaking the layout. I took t out. This td was my margin left of the body. So all the content went to the left. So I inserted align="center" to each table element which was in the body. BUM! It worked!

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 unclosed `<td>` tags in the HTML -- one on line 476, one on 482. That *might* be what's causing the issue in Gmail. If that doesn't fix it, I'd say yeah, it might be a colspan issue.